# Проблема с $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: php

Есть локальный сервер. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] почему-то дает результат "::1" вместо нормального "127.0.0.1". Что, собссна, не так?

```
$cookie_text = generateCookie(128);
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$suc_query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`, `password`, `cookie_ip`, `cookie_string`) VALUES (NULL, \"username\", SHA1('password'), " . $user_ip . ", \"{$cookie_text}\"";
echo($suc_query);
if($mysqli->query($suc_query) === TRUE) echo("GOTCHA!"); else echo("FUUUUUUUUUU!!!!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IPv6](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) - новый стандарт.  Теперь оно так...

Уже года 3-4 Apache передает в РНР адрес именно в таком виде. В угоду новому сетевому формализму. Это надо учитывать и в скриптах и в настройках (типа системного файла `host` для управления локальными хостами)

Comment: Рекомендую дать более развернутый ответ. Например пояснить почему у топикстартера браузер обращается на 127.0.0.1, а получает ::1

Comment: @tutankhamun, сделал

Comment: В httpd.conf изменил 
Listen 80
на
Listen 0.0.0.0:80

Все пошло, как надо. Спасибо за наводку!